# doctrine collection not working in twig for loop while sending email

Tags: symfony, email, doctrine-orm, twig

I'm sending an email of a sales quotation, everything seems to be fine, but when I iterate a OneToMany() collection in a for loop it doesn't display anything in the email, but it is shown perfectly when I open the same template in the browser.

Here is an screen capture from the browser which displays correctly.
[image]

And here is the image from email
[image]

Here is the code which I am using to display this fragment.

```
{% for c in sale.saleItems %}
    <tr>
        <td style="padding: 2px;">{{ c.getLineNo() }}</td>
        <td style="padding: 2px;">{{ c.getItemDesc() }}</td>
        <td style="padding: 2px;">{{ c.getOrderQty() }}</td>
        <td style="padding: 2px;">{{ c.getItem().getUnitCost() }}</td>
        <td style="padding: 2px;">{{ c.getUnitRate() }}</td>
        <td style="padding: 2px;">{{ c.getDiscountAmount() }}</td>
        <td style="padding: 2px;">{{ (c.getUnitRate() * c.getOrderQty()) - c.getDiscountAmount() }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Here is the code from the controller, I am using PHPMailer to send emails
[image]

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you show both the twig for your print controller and your Swiftmailer code?

Comment: use {{ dump(sale.saleItems) }}. i bet that this array is empty. Why is it empty? debug your controller action

Comment: @FrankB if array is empty then why it is showing the correct result when i open it in browser

Comment: Just a question: is `$sale` managed when passing it to `Twig`? Could you add something similar to `$sale = $entityManager->find('SALE_CLASS', $sale->getId());` before calling `renderView`?

Comment: @OscarPérez here is the code for getting sales entity `$sale = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Salesmaster')->find($id);` and `$id` is passed as method argument

Comment: @AhmedAli ok. Could you add it just before the line `$mail->msgHTML($this->renderView('sales/email.html.twig', array(
    'sale' => $sale,
)));`and give it a try?

Comment: If you echo the `renderView` output and then execute an `exit;`, are the lines displayed on screen?

Comment: Hi the Ahmed. Thanks for updating your post. So in your web controller are you also using the exact same code of: `$sale = $em-getRepository('AppBundle:Salesmaster')->find($id);` to get the sale value which you pass to your twig template? I'm just wondering if there is any difference? I didn't need to see the code for the emails, just the twig rendering and Entity Manager and how you get `sale` for both email controller and web controllers. Thanks!

Comment: @AlvinBunk here is the code for print controller `$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(); $sale = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Salesmaster')->find($id);`

Comment: @OscarPérez i tried your method and yes it is displaying lines on screen, this is what i did `echo $this->renderView('sales/email.html.twig', ['sale' => $sale]);` but still not displaying in emails

Comment: If with this method it is displaying correct data, then the problem is not in that line. It must be somewhere else. Are you sure you are sending exactly this email?

Comment: @OscarPérez this is exact code which i am using for sending emails